# How can I put objects of a derived type in a vector meant for the base type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I just started this project and I'm stuck on how I should implement my ChessBoard class. What I want is for my `std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece*>>` to store objects (the specific chess pieces) of a type derived from it.

See the assignment of the `std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece*>> board` in the ChessBoard class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class COLOR
{
    BLACK,
    WHITE,
    NOTHING
};

class ChessPiece
{
protected:
    COLOR color;

public:
    ChessPiece() = default;
    ChessPiece(COLOR c) : color{ c } {}
    COLOR get_color() const { return color; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const ChessPiece piece)
    {
        if (piece.color == COLOR::BLACK)
            return out << '-';
        if (piece.color == COLOR::WHITE)
            return out << '+';
    }
};

class King : public ChessPiece
{
private:
    bool moved;

public:
    King() = default;
    King(COLOR c) { color = c; }
    void set_moved(bool b) { moved = b; }
    bool has_moved() { return moved; }
};

class Queen : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:
    Queen() = default;
    Queen(COLOR c) { color = c; }
};

class Bishop : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:
    Bishop() = default;
    Bishop(COLOR c) { color = c; }
};

class Knight : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:
    Knight() = default;
    Knight(COLOR c) { color = c; }
};

class Rook : public ChessPiece
{
private:
    bool moved;

public:
    Rook() = default;
    Rook(COLOR c) { color = c; }
    void set_moved(bool b) { moved = b; }
    bool has_moved() { return moved; }
};

class Pawn : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:
    Pawn() = default;
    Pawn(COLOR c) { color = c; }
};

class Board
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece*>> board[8][8];

    Pawn white_pawn1(COLOR::WHITE), white_pawn2, white_pawn3, white_pawn4, white_pawn5, white_pawn6, white_pawn7, white_pawn8;
    Rook white_rook1, white_rook2;
    Knight white_knight1, white_knight2;
    Bishop white_bishop1, white_bishop2;
    Queen white_queen;
    King white_king;

    Pawn black_pawn1, black_pawn2, black_pawn3, black_pawn4, black_pawn5, black_pawn6, black_pawn7, black_pawn8;
    Rook black_rook1, black_rook2;
    Knight black_knight1, black_knight2;
    Bishop black_bishop1, black_bishop2;
    Queen black_queen;
    King black_king;

public:
    Board(std::string color)
    {
        if (color == "white")
        {
            **board =
            {
                { &black_rook1, &black_knight1, &black_bishop1, &black_queen, &black_king, &black_bishop2, &black_knight2, &black_rook2 },
                { &black_pawn1, &black_pawn2, &black_pawn3, &black_pawn4, &black_pawn5, &black_pawn6, &black_pawn7, &black_pawn8 },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { &white_pawn1, &white_pawn2, &white_pawn3, &white_pawn4, &white_pawn5, &white_pawn6, &white_pawn7, &white_pawn8 },
                { &white_rook1, &white_knight1, &white_bishop1, &white_queen, &white_king, &white_bishop2, &white_knight2, &white_rook2 }
            };
        }
        if (color == "black")
        {
            **board =
            {
                { &white_rook1, &white_knight1, &white_bishop1, &white_queen, &white_king, &white_bishop2, &white_knight2, &white_rook2 },
                { &white_pawn1, &white_pawn2, &white_pawn3, &white_pawn4, &white_pawn5, &white_pawn6, &white_pawn7, &white_pawn8 },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { &black_pawn1, &black_pawn2, &black_pawn3, &black_pawn4, &black_pawn5, &black_pawn6, &black_pawn7, &black_pawn8 },
                { &black_rook1, &black_knight1, &black_bishop1, &black_queen, &black_king, &black_bishop2, &black_knight2, &black_rook2 }
            };
        }
    }

    void print_board()
    {
        std::cout << "\ta\tb\tc\td\te\tf\tg\th\n1\t";
        for (int i = 0; i != 8; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j != 8; ++j)
            {
                if (board[i][j] == nullptr)
                    std::cout << '#' << std::endl;
                std::cout << board[i][j] << '\t';
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            if (i != 7)
                std::cout << i + 2 << '\t';
        }
    }

    ~Board() = default;
};

class Game
{
private:
    bool won;
    bool lost;

public:
    bool is_over();
    void update(std::string);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "white or black:\n";
    std::string color;
    std::cin >> color;

    // Start game with your given color on the bottom.
    // TODO throw exception if user enters an invalid color.
    Game game(color);
    std::string move;
    while (!game.is_over())
    {
        std::cin >> move;
        game.update(move);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What error are you getting?

Comment: "See the assignment of the std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece*>> board in the ChessBoard class" -- what exactly is there to be seen about it?

Comment: I can see the code. Are you getting compiler errors? Runtime errors? You haven't said what the actual error is that you're having.

Comment: Rather than deriving I think it will be better to have a common chess piece class and add other aspects as component or decorator  or just maintain a kind and use strategy for applying algorithms. This would be more flexible.

Comment: @Shubham Thanks for the input. I think I can make this work using each piece as a separate class. All along it was just a couple of dumb mistakes with using pointers.

Comment: Use smart pointers. See [`<memory>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: sure @user9111980 but, with inheritance how are you planning to upgrade a pawn to other piece? Also instead of using vector of vector you could also use an array of 8x8 and during initialization initialize a local array and do a mem copy. BTW are you aware what will std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece*>> board[8][8]; statment do??

Comment: I just updated the code again. To the best of my knowledge std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece*>> board[8][8]; I now have to deal with pointers to pointers. I'm also stuck on how I can initialize my Pawn class using an enum class. It's giving me an error: "const COLOR::WHITE is not a type name".

Comment: @user9111980 Please don't update the question with the answer, it makes the question and current answers stop making sense. If you have a new question, then ask it in a new entry.

Comment: @user9111980 for initialization you can use COLOR(WHITE) in place of COLOR::WHITE like white_pawn1(COLOR(WHITE)) . And std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece*>> board[8][8];  will create an 2 dim array of vector of vector of pointers to ChessPiece not 2D vector of ChessPiece pointer.

Answer (score 4):

```
Rook* white_rook1, white_rook2;
```

is not equivalent to

```
Rook* white_rook1;
Rook* white_rook2;
```

But

```
Rook* white_rook1;
Rook white_rook2;  // not a pointer !!!
```

(same for all other similar lines)
That's why the operator = can't match.

Also you don't have to use `std::vector` here: your board will not grow or shrink during the game (unless you have special rules :)). Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

You should note that none of your pointers is initialized in your code. As suggested by [Galik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47917887/3893262), it will be better to have objects instead and store their address in the `board`.

Comment: Or use `vector` with reserved size

Comment: Thanks for the input. All along it was just a couple of stupid mistakes using pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't create any actual objects. So far all your pointers are dangling. Also you have a whole set of game piece pointers as members *in addition* to your board.

It may be better to make your piece members actual objects rather than pointers and put their *addresses* into  your board using `&` (address of operator).

```
class Board
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<ChessPiece*>> board;

    // make these non-pointers (many of them already were)
    // and give their address to the board
    Pawn white_pawn1, white_pawn2, white_pawn3, white_pawn4, white_pawn5, white_pawn6, white_pawn7, white_pawn8;
    Rook white_rook1, white_rook2;
    Knight white_knight1, white_knight2;
    Bishop white_bishop1, white_bishop2;
    Queen white_queen;
    King white_king;

    Pawn black_pawn1, black_pawn2, black_pawn3, black_pawn4, black_pawn5, black_pawn6, black_pawn7, black_pawn8;
    Rook black_rook1, black_rook2;
    Knight black_knight1, black_knight2;
    Bishop black_bishop1, black_bishop2;
    Queen black_queen;
    King black_king;

public:
    Board(std::string color)
    {
        if (color == "white")
        {
            board =
            { // NOTE the use of & to take their address aand obtain a pointer
                { &black_rook1, &black_knight1, &black_bishop1, &black_queen, &black_king, &black_bishop2, &black_knight2, &black_rook2 },
                { &black_pawn1, &black_pawn2, &black_pawn3, &black_pawn4, &black_pawn5, &black_pawn6, &black_pawn7, &black_pawn8 },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { &white_pawn1, &white_pawn2, &white_pawn3, &white_pawn4, &white_pawn5, &white_pawn6, &white_pawn7, &white_pawn8 },
                { &white_rook1, &white_knight1, &white_bishop1, &white_queen, &white_king, &white_bishop2, &white_knight2, &white_rook2 }
            };
        }
```

By making the pieces proper objects they can maintain individual state and you do not have to worry about creating and destroying them - just moving them around (or onto or off of) the board.

Also I would consider using `std::array<std::array<ChessPiece*>, 8>, 8>` rather than vectors. But that will make your `Board` object larger.

Comment: Thanks for the input. All along it was just a couple of stupid mistakes using pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting anything by using vector here you can use 2D array instead. like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class EmptySquare : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:

};

class King : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:

};

class Queen : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:

};

class Bishop : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:

};

class Knight : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:

};

class Rook : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:

};

class Pawn : public ChessPiece
{
private:


public:

};

enum class COLOR
{
    BLACK,
    WHITE,
    NOTHING
};

class ChessPiece
{
private:
    COLOR color;

public:
    COLOR get_color();
};

class Board
{
private:
    ChessPiece* board[8][8];

    Pawn white_pawn1(COLOR(WHITE)), white_pawn2, white_pawn3, white_pawn4, white_pawn5, white_pawn6, white_pawn7, white_pawn8;
    Rook white_rook1, white_rook2;
    Knight white_knight1, white_knight2;
    Bishop white_bishop1, white_bishop2;
    Queen white_queen;
    King white_king;

    Pawn black_pawn1, black_pawn2, black_pawn3, black_pawn4, black_pawn5, black_pawn6, black_pawn7, black_pawn8;
    Rook black_rook1, black_rook2;
    Knight black_knight1, black_knight2;
    Bishop black_bishop1, black_bishop2;
    Queen black_queen;
    King black_king;

public:
    Board(std::string color)
    {
        if (color == "white")
        {
            ChessPiece* l_board[8][8] =
            {
                { &black_rook1, &black_knight1, &black_bishop1, &black_queen, &black_king, &black_bishop2, &black_knight2, &black_rook2 },
                { &black_pawn1, &black_pawn2, &black_pawn3, &black_pawn4, &black_pawn5, &black_pawn6, &black_pawn7, &black_pawn8 },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { &white_pawn1, &white_pawn2, &white_pawn3, &white_pawn4, &white_pawn5, &white_pawn6, &white_pawn7, &white_pawn8 },
                { &white_rook1, &white_knight1, &white_bishop1, &white_queen, &white_king, &white_bishop2, &white_knight2, &white_rook2 }
            };
            memcpy(board, l_board, sizeof(ChessPiece*) *8 *8);
        }
        if (color == "black")
        {
            ChessPiece* l_board[8][8] =
            {
                { &white_rook1, &white_knight1, &white_bishop1, &white_queen, &white_king, &white_bishop2, &white_knight2, &white_rook2 },
                { &white_pawn1, &white_pawn2, &white_pawn3, &white_pawn4, &white_pawn5, &white_pawn6, &white_pawn7, &white_pawn8 },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr },
                { &black_pawn1, &black_pawn2, &black_pawn3, &black_pawn4, &black_pawn5, &black_pawn6, &black_pawn7, &black_pawn8 },
                { &black_rook1, &black_knight1, &black_bishop1, &black_queen, &black_king, &black_bishop2, &black_knight2, &black_rook2 }
            };
            memcpy(board, l_board, sizeof(ChessPiece*) *8 *8);
        }
    }
    void print_board();

    ~Board();
};

class Game
{
private:
    bool won;
    bool lost;


public:
    bool is_over();
    void update(std::string);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "white or black:\n";
    std::string color;
    std::cin >> color;

    // Start game with your given color on the bottom.
    // TODO throw exception if user enters an invalid color.
    Game game(color);
    std::string move;
    while (!game.is_over())
    {
        std::cin >> move;
        game.update(move);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays can't be assigned to.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood.